# Does anybody know how to get the back-propagated errors to each layer in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

After the forward procedure, one loss and one error were generated for the batch data. Then according to the chain rule ,the error was back-propagated to the previous layers to update the parameters in each layer. Suppose I have the following network architecture:

```
 I->(W1)->C1->(W2)->C2->(W3)->O
```

`I` is the input, `O` is the output, `W1,W2,W3` is the weights for 3 layers. `C1` and `C2` are the outputs for the first two layers. With `O` and the ground truth, we obtain the loss and the error which will be back-propagated. My question is: In TensorFlow, are there any methods to get the errors back-propagated to `C1` and `C2`?

I know we could get the parameter operators as follows:

```
W1_op = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('W1')
W1_op = ...
```

My final purpose is to check if the errors are right in my network because I cannot check if the gradient in some certain layer (a new user-defined op) of this network is computed correctly. I want to check its gradient by checking the errors before and after this layer (by viewing the errors and comparing the errors).

I know that we could use the `tf.test.check_gradient` to do gradient check, but it seems the output for gradient check of this new operator depends on the inputs. In some cases, the  gradients check can be accepted (i.e., the theoretical gradient and the numerical gradient are very close evaluated by a threshold value, say, 1e-3), but in some other cases, the gradients check can fail, which depends on the parameters of that op. **Please see the figure. The `x-axis` (log-scaled) is the parameter, the `y-axis` is the difference between the computed gradients and the evaluated gradients. As shown in this figure, in some parameter configuration, the difference is very small, but in other cases, the gradient check will be fail.**

[image: fig]

Thus, I'm not sure if this is good or valid operator that is suitable for learning.

In the Caffe framework, it seems those `errors` were saved in `diff` memory for each layer. I want to get these back-propagated `errors` in each layer. Does anybody know how to get that?

Comment: If it's just for testing, you can loop with `tf.gradients` to get a jacobian if that's what you have theoretically. But I'm not sure I understand your objection to checking via finite differences. If there are some cases where they give different results, either the test needs to be modified to avoid non-smooth areas (or epsion decreased) or there's a real problem.

Comment: Hi, @AllenLavoie, thanks for your comment! I've updated the post with a figure, please kind have a check. Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to check the whole network simultaneously with finite differences? I'm guessing that very high and very low parameters are saturating the network (so I'd question whether your plot indicates correctness anywhere). I'd take the op you're interested in out of the network, potentially reading out some common inputs in the network (plus a few corner cases), then do finite differences on the op in isolation.

Comment: @AllenLavoie, for that figure, I didn't use the whole network, the test script was based on https://github.com/sadeepj/crfasrnn_keras/blob/master/src/test_gradients.py, which used the `tf.gradient_checker` for testing the gradients of self-defined operators.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Is the op itself highly non-linear at that point?

Comment: @AllenLavoie, the op did this: for each pixel `i`, the output is `u_j = \sum_{j=1}^N W_{ij} u_i`, `W_{ij}` is a weight depends on the image content (e.g. Gaussian kernel to measure the affinity between pixel `i` and its neighborhood). The related paper is https://graphics.stanford.edu/papers/permutohedral/permutohedral.pdf.

Comment: So the op computes `W_{ij}` too? Otherwise isn't that all linear (in which case finite differences should be exact)?

Comment: @AllenLavoie, yes, the op will compute the `W_{ij}` according to the values of pixel `i` and its neighbor pixels. `W_{ij}` means the similarity of nodes in graph. This op is for sharpening the edges according to image content.

Comment: In that case can you just decrease [`delta`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/test/compute_gradient)? Going to double precision if necessary.

Comment: @AllenLavoie, thanks. Yeah, it may be the numerical precision problem. But in general, we usually use the float precision. Even if we could pass the gradient check by decreasing `delta` as your suggested, could we still guarantee this op can be added into the network for valid learning? Thus, I resort to investigate the errors before and after this op layer to check if the errors were back-propagated correctly.

Comment: Decreasing `delta` just makes the finite differences approximation more sensitive to non-smooth functions; if the op is non-linear around 1, it may get you closer to the true gradient at that point. It's not cheating! You may run into numerical issues with a very small `delta` (too close to machine epsilon), but it's still your best option for verifying gradients.

Comment: @AllenLavoie, thanks a lot for your kind suggestions and comments!